# Scala implicit argument's type finding fail

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Trying to understand this case of implicit finding - [**finding implicit of an argument's type**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#implicit-scope-of-an-arguments-type). I copy-pasted the official example into the IDE and just changed the method name to **mul** like this:

```
class A(val n: Int) {
  def mul(other: A) = new A(n + other.n)
}
object A {
  implicit def fromInt(n: Int) = new A(n)
}
1 mul (new A(1))
```

Now it results in a compile-error saying:

```
value mul is not a member of Int
```

I also tried to experiment with **String** instead of **Int** which again resulted in compile error.

Can you explain what part I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `def +(other: A) =...` and `def mul(other: A) =...` is that `Int` has a `+` method but it does not have a `mul` method.

If the method exists, but not for the argument type being passed, then the compiler will look for an implicit conversion. Included in the implicit scope is the companion object of the passed parameter argument. If the implicit conversion is found then the entire expression is assessed for conversion.

If the method does not exist then an implicit conversion in the companion object is not within the implicit scope. It won't be found and no conversion takes place.

If you were to move the `implicit def fromInt(...` outside of the companion object then the `mul()` conversion will take place.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot ! That was exactly the problem. The method name should already exist on the object before implicits are applied.

Comment: very interesting, when this kind of resolution would be useful?

Comment: @Mikel; that's a good question. I don't know how/why the implicit scoping rules were decided upon. I was a bit surprised to learn about this one.

Comment: I tried to use `String` as type (of the field `n`), and use method name `product` (instead of `mul`). Now it won't compile again. How can we explain this one? If there's a type-parameter it won't work?

Comment: If you're changing from conversion-from-`Int` to conversion-from-`String` then the method name needs to be something that already exists in the `String` class, but not all methods appear to work. Methods like `split()` and `length()` work while methods like `product()`, `drop()`, and `head()` don't. I don't know why. It might have something to do with which methods are native to the `java.String` class and which are added by the Scala `StringOps` wrapper, but that's only a guess.